# Intellij Idea (live templates) – show predefined string while typing declaration

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, live-templates

I’m trying to create the live template that looks like this:

```
@org.testng.annotations.Test public void
$unit_of_work$_$state_under_test$_$expected_behavior$() {
  // GIVEN
  // WHEN
  // THEN
}
```

My params:

Abbreviation: test

Description: TestNG test

Type java:declaration

When I call this template by “test” name, I want to see somethin like this:

```
@Test public void
unit_of_work_state_under_test_expected_behavior() {
  // GIVEN
  // WHEN
  // THEN
}
```

And than override each variable (unit_of_work; state_under_test; expected_behavior)

Simply switching by using TAB key.

But instead I have something like this:

```
@Test public void
__() {
  // GIVEN
  // WHEN
  // THEN
}
```

It doesn’t show var names (hints).

So I’m trying to figure out where my mistake is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you edit your *live template*, click *Edit variables*. There you can define default values for your variables (the variables from your template should already be there).

Just fill out the *Default value* column. Make sure that the values are enclosed in double quotes (it is necessary if they are literal values), see [the documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/edit-template-variables-dialog.html).